# Wie würde man eine Person nennen, die äußerst glaubwürdig ist?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche ein Wort, welches jemanden beschreibt, der äußerst glaubwürdig ist. Also jemanden, bei dem **quasi niemand auf die Idee kommen würde, sie/ihn der Lüge zu bezichtigen,** bzw. jemanden, dem man vertraut.

Außer unantastbar, vertrauenswürdig und glaubwürdig fällt mir nichts ein.

Das gesuchte Wort sollte das fett Geschriebene betonen.

Comment: Noch ein paar weitere Wörter: "authentisch", "redlich"; eventuell "aufrichtig" noch.

Comment: @Em1 *redlich* und *aufrichtig* passen, aber *authentisch* kann auch der waschechte Ganove sein (Begriff ist mehrdeutig).

Comment: Absolut glaubwürdige Personen gibt es nicht und kann es nicht geben. Jeder Mensch ist fehlbar.

Comment: Dafür gibt es Wörter wie 'sehr', 'außergewöhnlich', 'überdurchschnittlich' usw. Absolut ist nun mal absolut - oder ein Vodka.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich würde eine solche Person **[integer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/integer)** nennen.

Allerdings setzt dies voraus, dass sie hohe moralische Ansprüche an sich selbst hat - formal kann auch ein aus Überzeugung **böse** handelnder Mensch als integer bezeichnet werden, wenn er damit seinem eigenen Wertesystem folgt. (Siehe Wikipedia zu [Integrität (Ethik)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrit%C3%A4t_(Ethik)))
Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch bedeutet *integer* allerdings *rechtschaffen **gut***.

Comment: Das klingt gut, es ist manchmal schwer das richtige Wort zu finden, mit etwas Abstand geht es dann leichter!

Comment: Ich würde integer eher mit Treue in Verbindung bringen. Eine Person, die integer ist, ist geeignet eine Lüge, die ihrer Organisation nutzt, zu verbreiten. Siehe auch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrit%C3%A4t_(Ethik)

Comment: Integer ist für mich das passende Wort, auch wenn es als Begriff weit über die reine Ehrlichkeit hinaus geht. Es bezieht auch eine ordentliche Portion Loyalität mit ein.

Comment: 'integer' trifft es sehr gut, auch wenn mir bei einer Frage zur deutschen Sprache vermutlich 'rechtschaffen' besser gefallen würde.

Answer (score 10):

wie wäre es mit **über jeden Zweifel erhaben**?

Comment: Uj jetzt regnet es quasi auch noch alternativen!

Answer (score 3):

Als Alternative würde ich noch ***[grundehrlich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/grundehrlich)*** ins Rennen werfen. Der Nachteil ist, dass es ausschließlich etwas darüber aussagt, welchen Wahrheitsgehalt die Äußerungen der Person haben, als darüber, wie die Person von anderen wahrgenommen wird.

Comment: Ich komme mir schon dumm vor, aber wie gesagt, wenn man lange über etwas brütet sieht man nicht über den Tellerrand, da ist eine andere Meinung sehr hilfreich!

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Keine Sorge; solche Fragen sind ein Grund dafür, warum diese Seite existiert.

Comment: Im Grundehrlichen schwingt aber auch Naivität mit. Glaubwürdig heißt aber auch, dass die Person kompetent genug ist eine vertrackte Frage richtig zu beantworten. Es gibt tausende, grundehrliche Aluhutträger denen jede Glaubwürdigkeit abgeht, weil sie durch und durch inkompetent sind.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Du hast an der falschen Stelle kommentiert.

Answer (score 0):

Als Alternative fällt mir da noch das übertragene *Institution* ein. So wie in:

> Dieser Mann/diese Frau ist eine Institution.

Comment: *Institution* ist für mich überhaupt nicht mit Ehrlichkeit verbunden, sondern mit Wissen und Fähigkeiten.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Das denke ich auch. Genau wie die **Koryphäe** ist es eher eine Autorität ihres Fachgebietes, egal wie sie sich sonst verhält.

Comment: Tatsächlich habe ich die Frage genau aus diesem Gesichtspunkt gesehen.

Comment: @frlan nein es ging mir eher um die Glaubwürdigkeit von Aussagen! Also eher etwas was vor Gericht benutzt würde! Aber Institution verdient auch ein 1+!

Comment: @Medi1Saif Ja. Ist aber spannend. Ich hätte nie unterstellt, dass jemand der eine besondere Kompetenz auf einem Fachgebiet hat, zumindest zu diesem Gebiet "lügen" würde. Wenn man sich Helmut Schmidt ansieht z.B. allgemein als Institution anerkannt gewesen und gleichzeitig auch als aufrichtig etc. in der Gesellschaft bewertet

Comment: @frlan: Als aufrichtig habe ich Schmidt noch niemanden beschreiben gehört. Und ich könnte wetten, dass nicht nur FJ Strauß, sondern auch die Mehrheit seiner Wähler, Schmidt nicht glaubwürdig fanden, also weit entfernt von 'quasi niemand', wie in der Frage gefordert.